# How to empty SQLite DB for iOS distribution/ Generic iOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I just submitted an app to the App store and it is now available. Unfortunately I realized that my development test data was included in the SQLite database! How do I go about emptying my database for the distribution, in other words removing all rows from tables? I know how to do this for a simulation (Reset content and settings), but since the deployed version just uses the Generic iOS build that does not run in the simulator, I am not sure how to clear the database.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself. You have to find the location of the sql file in your project.

1. Find the .sql file in your project.
2. Go to File-> Show in Finder
3. Then go to that location using Terminal and use sqlite3 to set up your DB as you want it.